# How to get an apache core dump?

Tags: server, apache2, 14.10, debugging, gdb

I am having problems with my 14.10 Ubuntu Server. Upon performing certain actions my apache2 restarts with a segmentation fault error. In order to debug this issue I would like to create a core dump. I have done the following:

- added `CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/apache-coredumps` to the config file
- Run `ulimit -c unlimited`
- Run `apt-get install apache2-dbg php5-dbg`
- restarted `apache` and caused the error. The log claims there may be a core dump in the directory, however it is empty.

I also tried to use gdb directly on the executable of apache2, but apache won't start unless started through `apachectl` or `service apache2 start`.

How can I get a core dump to debug my issue OR how can I attach `gdb` directly to apache?

Comment: For the former, look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/470407/how-to-get-a-core-dump-from-apache-when-segfaulting for the latter, here: http://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html#gdb

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I tried setting the permissions as suggested in the first link, however still no core is dumped. I already knew the second link. It doesn't really answer my question in an ubuntu specific manner (Ubuntu doesn't have an httpd executable, and calling apache2 directly doesn't work for previously mentioned reasons).

Comment: Is the coredump in /tmp instead perhaps?

Comment: I specified the core dump to be placed in a different folder, so it's not in /tmp.

Comment: I don't want to use apport, I want to examine my problem locally and not report an error, because it's probably not an apache bug.

Comment: This doesn't really help. Keep in mind I'm on Ubuntu server, only connected  via ssh. Apport seems to be a GUI to create core dumps.

Comment: No problem. It's a hosted virtual server so no point in ram testing. Segfaults often occur when there are incompatibilities for example with php.

Comment: Did you see this? http://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html

Comment: possibly related: ulimit -c unlimited only effects your current shell session. You can check limits of httpd by looking in /proc.  `cat /proc/$(pidof httpd)/limits`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ulimit -c unlimited` only effects your current shell.

You can confirm this by looking at output `cat /proc/$(pidof -s apache2)`.

I added `ulimit -c unlimited` to `/etc/default/apache2` and now `cat /proc/$(pidof -s apache2)/limits` includes

```
Max core file size        unlimited            unlimited            bytes
```

Comment: I tried this but it still didn't get Apache (12 LTS) to dump core. Any thoughts?

Comment: Found the answer - apport was enabled in `/etc/default/apport`, and it changed the kernel core dump pattern to suit itself. See http://serverfault.com/questions/470407/how-to-get-a-core-dump-from-apache-when-segfaulting

Comment: echo '/tmp/apache-coredumps/core-%e.%p' > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern